# How to configure mule requester?

Tags: mule, mule-component

I get messages from one jms queue. I'm using mule requester component but how can i give that jms queue path in resources option ?

Please assist me., Thanks.,

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial ? http://fr.slideshare.net/anir37/using-mule-requester-for-jms . Tell us if that help you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in the queue in URL format:

```
<mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="jms://input?connector=AMQConnector1" doc:name="Request a message from a queue" />
```

Comment: It is working fine if I have only one activemq-connector (<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" ....., ) . but in my case I'm using 3 activemq-connectors so when I define <mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="jms://input" doc:name="Request a message from a queue" /> there is a confusion to which activemq-connector it should refer? that is y I'm facing error message as " There are at least 2 connectors matching protocol "jms", so the connector to use must be specified on the endpoint using the 'connector' property/attribute."

Comment: Updated my answer to include how to specify the connector. Use the ?connector param in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The Mule config will be :
-`<mulerequester:config name="Mule_Requester" doc:name="Mule Requester"/> <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" specification="1.1" doc:name="Active MQ"/> <flow name="QueueRequester" doc:name="QueueRequester"> <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="fetch" doc:name="HTTP"/> <mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="jms://input" doc:name="Request a message from a queue" /> <logger message="Payload from JMS message: #[payload]" level="WARN" doc:name="Logger"/> </flow>`

Now suppose there is a JMS queue named input from where we need to fetch data in our flow on we hit the url : `http://localhost:8081/fetch '.

Comment: It is working fine if I have only one activemq-connector (<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" ....., ) . but in my case I'm using 3 activemq-connectors so when I define    <mulerequester:request config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="jms://input" doc:name="Request a message from a queue" />   there is a confusion to which activemq-connector it should refer? that is y I'm facing error message as "  There are at least 2 connectors matching protocol "jms", so the connector to use must be specified on the endpoint using the 'connector' property/attribute."

Comment: @Thiru to be honest i never saw this kind of error or configuration system and i think i'm not able to help you more .. Keep search on google . Sorry